# How to generate proper labelled image from MATLAB (Image Labeler) for image segmentation

Tags: matlab, tensorflow, dataset, image-segmentation, deeplab

I get black image whenever exporting labels to file in the Image Labeler App in MATLAB R2019a

Here is what i do:

```
Export Labels > To File
```

Also, I know that PNG file's image value is composed as 0 1 2 and this is the reason image apperas black.
[image: b]

I tried this piece of code and I get the result with distingished but the dimensions of the image are changed.

```
    figure;
    [i, m] = imread('PixelLabelData/Label_1.png');
    imshow(i,m);
```

[image]

I need is Labelled png image with proper dimensions. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using https://supervise.ly instead of MATLAB. Development is much easier and faster.